# Making rabbitMQ connection globally

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

currently I have

```
async def send_rabbitmq(msg = {}):
    connection = await connect("amqp://guest:guest@localhost/")

    channel = await connection.channel()

    await channel.default_exchange.publish(
        Message(json.dumps(msg.dict()).encode("utf-8")),
        routing_key = "fastapi_task"
    )

    await connection.close()
```

what I want to do is make a connection globally so all functions can access it

however when I'm removing `connection = await connect("amqp://guest:guest@localhost/")` and making globally `connection = connect("amqp://guest:guest@localhost/")` I'm getting `AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'channel'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your code, when you use await, the next statement that accesses the channel will find that object if the connection is successfully made.
`connection = await connect("amqp://guest:guest@localhost/")`

In the second statement
`connection = connect("amqp://guest:guest@localhost/")` you are not awaiting for the connection to be made, that's why you get your printed error.

If you want to make the connection variable global, declare a connection variable outside of the function, and inside your function use `global` keyword to set that variable.

Inside function:

```
 global connection 
 connection = await connect("amqp://guest:guest@localhost/")
```